# How to reduce the coordinates returned by OSRM Server?

Tags: routes, leaflet, coordinates, osrm

I have an application which shows the routes between locations and I am using OSRM with Leaflet. Every time when I am getting routes from the OSRM server it gives details including `coordinates` on the route. I see depending on the route it's giving lots of coordinates and the following image has 4035 coordinates for a route. I have two questions,

1. What is the distance between each coordinate? Is it a fixed distance between each coordinate or how is it selecting those coordinates?
2. Is there a way to reduce the coordinates I am getting from the server? For example, if I need coordinates from every 10 miles on that particular route can I get them?

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Leaflet will perform a Douglas-Peucker simplification of the line before drawing, it, so there's no real need to worry about this.

Comment: Actually, I need to loop through coordinates for a reason. So is there a way I can reduce and get coordinates from every 10 miles or so?

Comment: Are you also using `leaflet-routing-machine` ?

Comment: @Gurgolo Yes I am using `leaflet-routing-machine`.

Comment: To answer question 1 succinctly, the coordinates are not equidistant.
The library does not provide what you are asking for, so I guess you have to write 2 lines of code.
Given that you have an array of coordinates available you could quickly and roughly calculate the distance using the Haversine formula, take the closest point at 10 miles and move on to the next one. Or, even more roughly, take the total distance and divide it by the gap you are interested in. In this case if I read it right it would be 1 point for every 18 or so. Would such a solution be OK or not?

Comment: @Gurgolo Actually, I was looking for an already implemented solution may be from OSRM or from Leaflet. The issue is I didn't want to loop through the coordinates array and do some filtering, checking etc because for a long route there may be more than 30K, 40K, or 50K+ coordinates. So I wanted to cut down that coordinates looping time from my application and instead get the desired results from OSRM or Leaflet. But if there is no such way already implemented and filtering is the only way then yes this solution will be ok.